# Is passing object property against Dependency Inversion Principle? Please advise

Tags: design-patterns, solid-principles, dependency-inversion

Assuming there are classes as follow.

```cs
interface Book {
  Guid Id { get; }
  Guid AuthorId { get; }
}

interface Author {
  Guid Id { get; }
  void Autograph();
}
```

Then there are service and data store

```cs
interface AutographService {
  void Sign(Guid bookId);
}

interface BookStore {
  Book GetBookById(Guid bookId);
}
```

Given that the entry point is to call `AutographService.Sign(bookId)`, there are `BookStore` and `AuthorStore` injected into `AutographService`. Does the following data store violate Dependency Inversion Principle?

```cs
interface AuthorStore {
  Author GetAuthorById(Guid authorId);
}
```

And how about the following instead?

```cs
interface AuthorStore {
  Author GetAuthorByBookId(Guid bookId);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Dependency inversion principle states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle):

- High-level modules should not import anything from low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions (e.g., interfaces).
- Abstractions should not depend on details. Details (concrete implementations) should depend on abstractions.

Let's see these principles more carefully according your code snippets.

- High-level modules should not import anything from low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions (e.g., interfaces).

You are using interfaces. And interface is an abstraction. It is not concrete implementation. So you are okay with this state.

- Abstractions should not depend on details. Details (concrete implementations) should depend on abstractions.

As your abstraction `AuthorStore` implements interface `interface AuthorStore` and you are injecting this abstraction into your service. So it can be concluded that this principle is complied.